# Fail to get request from Gettyimages API

Tags: javascript

Hello fellow programmers i want to use Gettyimages API in my project. I have found the example on [github](https://github.com/gettyimages/gettyimages-api/blob/master/code-samples/JavaScript.md) how to implement get request. In my opinion i follow instructions correctly, nevertheless fail to get request. When i console in the browser it shows nothing.

My code looks like that.

```
var apiKey ="z4pn22dn47rc7bsjw4jwxv9q";
var appendApiKeyHeader = function( xhr ) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Api-Key', apiKey)
};

var searchRequest = { "phrase": "dog" }


function GetSearchResults(callback) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend:appendApiKeyHeader,
    url: "https://api.gettyimages.com/v3/search",
    data: searchRequest
  }).success(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 

    console.log(data);

  }).fail(function (data, err) {

    console.log(err); 

  });
}
```

Please point out my mistake. If you want you can find my project on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/nazimkazim/pen/zBbxyW)

Comment: You must be getting some form of error. Have you checked your webserver logs?

Comment: Did you hit the service in a browser with the required parameter and check if it is still working and getting a valid response.

Comment: As far as i understand, yes. Strangely error is not shown even in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your not calling the function. Not 100% sure, but as far as I can see you need to specify what you are searching for i.e. images or videos. Running below code will give the following results.

```
var apiKey ="z4pn22dn47rc7bsjw4jwxv9q";
var appendApiKeyHeader = function( xhr ) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Api-Key', apiKey)
};

var searchRequest = { "phrase": "dog" }


function GetSearchResults() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend:appendApiKeyHeader,
    url: "https://api.gettyimages.com/v3/search/videos",
    data: searchRequest
  }).success(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 

    console.log(data);

  }).fail(function (data, err) {

    console.log(data); 

  });
}

GetSearchResults();
```

Result:

```
{
  result_count:0,
  videos: []
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! It helped!

Comment: @Roelof how can I add username and password to get images from a particular account?